# Unable to zoom in after animating camera on Google Maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

This is code i am using to animate camera to a route between two markers.But the problems is,after animating I am unable to zoomin or zoomout.If I am zooming in,it is going to the initial position..Please help me...Here's my code.

```
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(loc);
            builder.include(nuz);

            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            int padding = (int) (width *0.10);

            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,width,height,padding);
            mMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Comment: zooming into `Initial position'  ? or current position?

Comment: current postion

Comment: maybe in onResume you are zooming in your current locaiton ...remove that